# IMU ros orientation

Tags: ros, imu, sensor-msgs, yaw

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

This is a 2 part question:

1. I am building a differential drive robot. Which uses encoders and imu to get the orientation of the robot. The imu is an MPU9150 with TM4c1294xl microcontroller. I have successfully fused the gyro and magnetometer via a kalman filter to get an estimate of yaw (referenced with the initial conditions). I want to be able to publish yaw output from my imu via the rosserial package. I will be publishing the yaw output only, so my euler orientation should be (0,0,yaw) right? And which orientation convention does ros use. I am using North-East-Down(NED). I am using udoo board which is running rosserial on its arduino compatible microcontroller. The udoo is connected via i2c to my TM4c1294xl. My question is , does ros provide standard msg type to support euler angles from an imu ? could anyone please point me into the right direction.
2. Would i be better off by tilt compensating my magnetometer rather than just assume that the robot drives on plane surface through out. What are the pros and cons of not implementing it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202352/imu-ros-orientation/) by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As for the ROS axis convention, have a look at [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#axis-orientation).
Moreover, ROS has defined the [IMU msg](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html) format to hold data from an IMU.

---

Originally posted by [Kristof](https://answers.ros.org/users/5409/kristof/) with karma: 141 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2015-02-03**:
See also [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/50870/what-frame-is-sensor_msgsimuorientation-relative-to/).

**Comment by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on 2015-02-05**:
@Kristof: According to REP-103 & 105. The body frame is to be oriented (+X- north, +Y-west, +z-up). My imu uses (+Y-north, +X-east, +Z-up). should i be converting these orientations in the imu processing itself or i could somehow convert these notations under ROS?.

**Comment by [Kristof](https://answers.ros.org/users/5409/kristof/) on 2015-02-06**:
@asusrog
It is probably best to convert to the ROS orientations at the moment you put the information from your imu into a ROS IMU msg. If you have full control over the firmware of your imu, you could also change it there - but this might be harder to maintain.